# python - no output nor error message

Tags: python

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"

r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a")

g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "content"})  

n_data = soup.find_all("strong", {"class": "fullname show-popup-with-id "})

c_data = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text"})

for item in g_data:

    try:

        print(item.contents[0].find_all(n_data)[0].text)

    except:

        pass
```

When i tried running the above code, no error message was shown. The only thing displayed was runfile(myfilepath),wdir(anotherpath). I was expecting the output to print name which in this case will be "Donald Trump". Any help or suggestion? I am using spyder(python 3.6) as my platform.

Comment: You actually silenced all errors with your try block.

Comment: what do you mean by that? Btw, i space out the above code for better visual purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `print(item.contents[0].find_all(n_data)[0].text)` should be `print(item.find_all("strong", {"class": "fullname show-popup-with-id "})[0].text)`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://twitter.com/realDonaldTrump?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

links = soup.find_all("a")
g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "content"})  
n_data = soup.find_all("strong", {"class": "fullname show-popup-with-id "}) 
c_data = soup.find_all("p", {"class": "TweetTextSize TweetTextSize--normal js-tweet-text tweet-text"})

for item in g_data:
    try:
        print(item.find_all("strong", {"class": "fullname show-popup-with-id "})[0].text) # chain the n_data here
    except:
        pass
```

The output will be

`Donald J. Trump
...
...
...
Donald J. Trump`

Comment: Hi, i have tried it and it passed! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code

```
    except:

        pass
```

effectively suppresses error messages.

Comment: Hi, i tried taking away the exception and will have an result of "unexpected EOF while parsing". But when i take out the try i will have "'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'". Sorry if this is a stupid question but im totally new to python.

Comment: The `try:` requires `except:`, so "unexpected EOF while parsing" (*EOF* means *End Of File*) - the parser expected `except:` but it never reached it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation! I somehow expected it it, but still did trial and error to see if it works. Thank anyway!